# Can't find the keyboard shortcut in keymap preferences

Tags: customization, shortcut

I am a Maya user and I want to move to Blender and I decided to Change the Keymap to a similar look to Maya; But couldn't find the shortcut key for **' Spacebar + W ' as Tweak tool** to Remove It and use the shortcut for Move gizmo.

[image: I have changed anything I wanted but I need to Remove this to use 'spacebar + W' as Move gizmo not Tweak tool]

Can anybody Help me Please?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the keymap in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Keymap*) and select *Key-binding* in the drop-down next to the search box. The shortcut can be found by searching for the <kbd>W</kbd> key-binding. The <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> shortcut for the toolbar popup is a separate one.

[image: Search by key-binding]

You're looking for *Set Tool By Name*. (*)

[image: Set Tool By Name]

(*) Now that you know its name, you can also search for it directly. The approach above works for any shortcut though, in case you don't know the operator's label.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One thought - how did you know *Set Tool By Name* is the correct one? :) I can't see any indication it's the *Tweak tool*.

Comment: It's the only tool with the W key binding under the toolbar popup. By changing the key-binding you can see that it changes the tweaks tools shortcut as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the popup doesn't show Python tooltips for its entries, however you can still get the underlying operator by enabling the Developer Extras in *Edit > Preferences > Interface*. In the toolbar right click on the *Tweak* entry. Select *Copy Python Command* and paste it in the text editor. This will give you the name of the operator which you can also search for in the keymap. In this case it's `bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name="builtin.select")` which means you'd be searching for `tool_set_by_id`. *Online Python References* works as well, it will open the Blender's Python API manual.

Comment: Thanks again for the added info. Never realized those python tooltips can be useful even for non-developers. Good to know :).

Comment: Really Thank You. it was really helpfull